# How to avoid this bad for loop?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to loop through a big number (6 billion to be exact), but I can't because my computer freezes. How can I work my way around this. I'm supposed to find the largest prime factor of `600851475143`.

```
function prime(n) {
    if (n === 1 || n === 2) return false;
    if (n % 2 === 0 || n % 3 === 0) return false;
    return true;
}
var n = 600851475143;
for (var i = 1, c = []; i < n; i++) {
    if ((n % i === 0) && prime(i)) {
        c.push(i);
    }
}
```

I'm done with it yet. I'm storing the primes in an array.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but the prime function is not doing what the name suggests it is doing.  For example, it will indicate that 25 is prime.

Comment: Try this: http://bit.ly/K2BRTA

Comment: Your "prime" function is basically saying "1, 2, and multiples of 2 and 3 are prime"

Comment: Are you running the script in a browser?

Comment: also that's ~600 billion not ~6 billion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `prime()` function doesn't do what the name says it should. There are many efficient ways of factoring primes, try this one for example:

```
var x = 600851475143;
var i = 2;
var sk;
while(i <= x) 
{
    while (x % i == 0)
    {
        sk = i;
        x = x / i;
    }
    i++;
}
console.log(sk);
```

Output: `6857`

[This](http://www.btinternet.com/~se16/js/factor.htm) page has another (view source) function for factoring.

Answer (score 1):

That `prime` function doesn't returns prime numbers only, but all those positive integers that aren't 1 or divisible by 2 and 3.

Let's see the whole algorhythm again. First of all, notice that you don't need to iterate through `n`, you can stop at its square root (think about it).

```
var divs = [];
if (!(n & 1)) { // Checking if n is even, using faster bit operators
    divs.push(2);
    while (!(n & 1)) n >>= 1;
}
var d = 3, l = Math.sqrt(n);
while (d < l) {
    if (!(n % d)) {
        divs.push(d);
        while (!(n % d)) n /= d;
        l = Math.sqrt(n);
    }
    d += 2; // No even numbers except 2 are prime, so we skip them
}
if (n !== 1) divs.push(n);
```

Now `divs[divs.length - 1]` contains your largest prime divisor of `n`, and `divs` all the prime factors.